# Showing [object Object] in the place where it is supposed to show the actual component inside Angular Tabs

Tags: angular

I am working on the Angular Tabs and loading the components dynamically in the tabs. I am able to load the components and bubble the events from the dynamic component i.e. pass both @Input and @Output parameters.

But now I am facing the issue of the components are not being placed in the correct tabs i.e. all the components are getting loaded in the first tab itself. It is showing `[object Object]` in the place where it is supposed to show the actual component in the other tabs i.e Child1, Child2 etc...

I have replicated this issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7fnhd-cd6yjj?file=app%2Fhome.component.ts)

My requirement is it show the actual components in the place of `[object Object]` and not all in the first tab. I should be able to instantiate the Component2 in child2,child3 tabs

I have checked in the demo code in [GitHub](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/AngularTabsDemo)

Comment: What do you mean by "show the actual components"

Comment: it should display Component2 in the Child1 and Child2 tabs

Comment: I don't know if other people are experiencing it too but I have not been able to look at your code since you posted it. Either I get a timeout or a HTTPS socket error. Can you try reposting it to jsfiddle instead?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7fnhd-cd6yjj?file=app%2Fhome.component.ts

Comment: I have pushed the demo code in Github url https://github.com/snkrishnan1/AngularTabsDemo

Comment: You might be able to include just the relevant parts in the question itself. e.g. I think the important code is `addTab` and your `{{ tab.templateRef }}` binding in the component's template. You're having problems trying to bind a class using the interpolation syntax. [This](https://medium.com/@caroso1222/angular-pro-tip-how-to-dynamically-create-components-in-body-ba200cc289e6) guide might get you started.

Comment: thanks for your link, I am not understanding the mistake I am doing it in the interpolation syntax. What is the change I need to do and how to bind the class? If possible can you please correct it in the stackblitz link by forking it and share it with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code

1. Why it creates in first tab: The code is using ViewChild. Using viewchild will give the first available component. The *ngFor is generating one placeholder in each tab. However, since ViewChild is used, every time, only the first one is used. Further, since the first placeholder is in the first tab. It always creates new component in the first tab.
2. Why you see object: object. You are binding the childcomponet to templateRef. templateRef is string. Hence what happens (probably) is that toString would be called on an object and for child2 this generates object:object
3. How to fix: Having fix with correct design can take long time. However, I have tried to quickly fix your code. the highlight of changes I did
   a. ViewChildren instead of ViewChild.
   b. First I add the tab so that I can get the viewchildren bound for further use.
   c. since view children are not bound till next cycle, I am using setTiemout. Thought this is not the best design. better design would be ti do this on tabAdded event - which I dont see in spec of tab.
   d. Used the last placeholder to add component. This would add the child to the last tab which is what we want.

https://angular-e7fnhd-ihumnz.stackblitz.io
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7fnhd-ihumnz

Comment: Is it possible to redirect to the newly loaded tab, currently in the stackblitz - after loading a new tab it still shows the first tab. instead it show me the newly loaded tabs. I tried adding  [(selectedIndex)]="activeTabIndex" logic in the <md-tab-group> but it is breaking the funtionality. Can you please help me?

Comment: If you do two way binding with activeTabIndex, then it might modify the value of active tab index whenever you come back to the first tab to create one more new tab. Probably something like this is what you are expecting. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7fnhd-s1azfx. Here I am maintaining a new variable so that dual binding will not impact it.